# Sequelize findAll() unless a parameter for WHERE is given?

Tags: sql, sequelize.js

I wen't through the sequelize docs and didn't recognize anything that would work for this. I need to find all posts in a database unless a "where" condition is given. If a condition is given, use that condition. Basically `SELECT * OR WHERE something = something FROM somedatabase`. Is there a way of achieving this through sequelize?

Answer (score 0):

You just have to pass the condition of *empty object*, it will then do the find all:

```
Post.findAll({
  where: {
    authorId: 2
  }
});
// SELECT * FROM post WHERE authorId = 2

Post.findAll({
  where: {
  }
});
// SELECT * FROM post
```